# Create new apps from command line

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to automatize the deployment of new Java apps on Google App Engine and I want to know if there is any way to create a new App without going to the App Engine Administration Console webpage. I have read the appcfg.cmd documentation but there is no command to create a new App. I have also read the documentation in Google Developers and it seems that the only way to create it is doing from the webpage.

Comment: if the documentation says so, then you can't.